# loadFixtures method in jest.js

Tags: jquery, jestjs

Is there an equivalent method to loadFixtures method in jest. I can't seem to find anything in the jest docs. I'd like to be able to load a html fixture into jest test file ?

Or is there another way of doing html stub in jest that I'm missing ?

Note i'm not using React as its an old project with Jquery.

So instead of writing something like.

```
window.$ = require('jquery');

beforeEach(() => {


    document.body.innerHTML =
        '<div>' +
        ' <input id="exMonth" value="02" />' +
        ' <input id="exYear" value="2017" />'
        '</div>';

});


test("exMonth should be 02", () =>{

    expect($('#exMonth').val()).toBe('01');

});
```

I'd like to abstract my html out to a html fixture file and require it to the

```
document.body.innerHTML = require(myHtmlFixture.html)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried? Hard to offer help without seeing what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: All i'm trying to do is load a html file so I can run tests against it. Not much to show. Jasmine I use loadFixtures method.

Comment: Ok added a simple jquery example of what I'd like to do in my post.

Answer (score 3):

You could use node's `fs` for serverside tests.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var htmlFixture = fs.readFileSync('spec/fixtures/myFixture.html')

document.body.innerHTML = htmlFixture;
```

see: https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs